# Page as archive with custom permalink structure not working

Tags: wordpress

I've a custom post type named "references" and I added a function so I can use the category as part of the permalink. I'm declaring the custom slug like so:

```
'slug'  => '/references/%category%',
```

and then use a filter to manipulate it:

```
function change_post_link($post_link, $id = 0) {
    $post = get_post($id);
    if ($post->post_type == 'references') {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'category');
        if ($terms) {
            return str_replace('%category%', $terms[0]->slug, $post_link);
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

That part works fine, I'm getting URLs like "/references/cars/the-red-one".

But now I can't have a page (the default type) at "/references/cars", it only works if I'm not using a placeholder for the custom post type.

Do you have any ideas how this could be solved? 'has_archive' is false btw.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

Find Category Slug:

```
$categories = get_categories(); 
    foreach ($categories as $cat) 
    {
        $cat_slug = $cat->slug;
    }
```

Create New URL:

```
$new_url = esc_url(add_query_arg(array( 'category' => $cat_slug,), $old_url));
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best solution but at least it works now. Here you go:

I've added a hidden **dummy post type** with the slug **"references/dummy"**. This seems to force Wordpress to recognize the correct (debateable...) permalink structure.